# Oracle Transparent Data Encryption

Tags: encryption, pci-dss

Currently we are using Vormetric for Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) in the Oracle Standard product to satisfy PCI-DSS 2.0 requirements. Does anyone have experience with other third party solutions for TDE? Using Oracle Enterprise and the Advanced Security Option (ASO) has been cost prohibitive to this point. We've gotten mediocre support from Vormetric and are evaluating alternate solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately this is offtopic, as shopping-type questions are on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you are aware that Oracle does provide a TDE solution.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/advanced-security/index-099011.html

The only time I seen this solution being cost effective if your company was large enough to have a global contract with Oracle.

Comment: And that's the rub - Oracle software is expensive. I'm just brainstorming different ways to avoid the Oracle ASO cost. Since the choice comes down to a price and admin overhead comparison of different solutions, we may end of still using ASO. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score -1):

check for RDC Software.
http://www.prweb.com/releases/2010/06/prweb4167634.htm

Comment: Welcome to IT Security! Could you give an answer with more substance besides just a link?